# magento add many additional price to cart, and user can choose one

Tags: magento, cart

Assumption : A customer added a mobile phone worth ₹2000 to cart
Situation : Our client wants the customer to select one recharge amount for eg. ₹100(from many available recharge amount eg. ₹50, ₹100, ₹150, ₹200, ₹250) in cart, these amount can be added from admin backend. And the final price of product is ₹2100. (for each product customers have to select the recharge amount seperately)
Modifying the price would reflect in many areas like invoice, email exchange, checkout total.

In which module the price calculations are there? and whats the better way to achieve this?

Any steps to do this or a sample piece of code would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: then go for choose custom option of product

Comment: Wow! Thanks nd Sry I never noticed that custom options. This is exactly what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then go for choose custom option of product...
catalog>manage product>Add product[Or Choose your existing product] >Custom option > Add Option > Input Type >Drop Down or Radio  button 
Add option as you want
it will solve your problem

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.